# sql left join explanation

Tags: sql

Found this code example online regarding sql left joins and I want to make sure i get it correctly ( since I am no expert )

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field AND table1.common_field_2 = table2.common_field_2
WHERE table1.column3 = ... AND table2.common_field IS NULL
```

My question comes for the `AND table2.common_field IS NULL` part and how it affects the ON above.

For me it seems that join result will contain only those that they exist on table1, but not on table2 based on the common_field.

Is that correct? Can it be written simpler since the above seems confusing to me.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct.  The logic can be replaced using `NOT EXISTS` and usually with `NOT IN` as well (although I recommend `NOT EXISTS`).

Comment: While I do agree with Gordon's assessment, I have to wonder why then you would select anything from table2. `Table2.column2` (in your example).  Every value selected would be NULL because of the where clause.  So if the null column(s) is/are required in the resulting data-set, a not in or not exists would not work as the table column wouldn't be accessible in the result set.  So you would have to use null column_name if you needed those columns in the result set if using not in/not exists.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in any SQL development is to check the data that is actually stored in the tables you intend to use in your query. 
How the data is stored will affect the results of the query, particularly when filtering for `NULL`s or checking for the existence of a row.
Using `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` to check for existence/non-existence of one or more rows is very effective, providing the `WHERE` clause within the `EXISTS` sub-query doesn't have conflicting logic (e.g. `NOT EXISTS` and `<>` are used together), which can be confusing and produce results that are difficult to test.

Does `table2.common_field` contain any `NULL`s? If it does, it would be wise to filter on those in a nested query, CTE or view first, then use the results of that in the main query.
If `table2.common_field` doesn't contain `NULL`s or has a `NOT NULL` constraint, then perhaps you are using `table2.common_field` `IS NULL` to filter on the results of the `LEFT JOIN`, where there is no match on the join criteria for `table2`. If this is the case and you want to stick with using `LEFT JOIN`, I recommend to nest your query and filter on the `NULL` in the outer query.

Here's a couple of options:

**Option 1: Use `LEFT JOIN`, filter on `NULL` in the outer query.**

Note the careful use of an alias for `table2.common_field` which is important.

```
SELECT
result.*
FROM
(
    SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2, table2.common_field as table2_common_field...
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field AND table1.common_field_2 = table2.common_field_2
    WHERE table1.column3 = ...
) result
WHERE result.table2_common_field IS NULL;
```

**Option 2 (recommended): Use `NOT EXISTS`.**

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  select 1
                  from table2
                  where table2.common_field = table1.common_field
                  AND table2.common_field_2 = table1.common_field_2
                 )
AND table1.column3 = ...
```

Comment: Fixed syntax bug in Option 2 - Replaced WHERE with AND.